# How to create group of Enums with common property

Tags: java, class, enums

I have a `Class` that contains a group of `public Strings`. And I would like to group them, so that accessing them from another `Class` is less confusing.

For example the following line would print the field.

```
System.out.println(ClassName.GroupName.FIELD);
```

The way I've implemented this is:

```
public class ClassName{
    public static class GroupName{
        public static final String FIELD = "TEXT";
        public static final String FIELD1 = "TEXT";
    }
    public static class GroupName1{
        public static final String FIELD2 = "TEXT";
    }
}
```

But I think using `enums` for this kind of task would be more efficient.

The problem is that I would have to write this for each group:

```
public enum GroupName{
    FIELD ("TEXT"), FIELD1 ("TEXT");

    private String text;

    Extra(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString() {  
        return text;
    }
}
```

So the `Class` would become too big, and frankly it wouldn't look as neat.

I would prefer it if I could do something like:

```
public class EnumInterface{
    private String text;

    public EnumInterface(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return text;
    }

}

public enum GroupName extends EnumInterface{
    FIELD("TEXT"), FIELD1("TEXT")
}
```

But unfortunately `enums` cannot extend `classes` and if `EnumInterface` was an actual `interface` then I would not be able to have the `field`, `constructor`, or `method` there.

Any recommendations?

Comment: "But I think using enums for this kind of task would be more efficient." What is the efficiency gain you envisage? The most efficient way to represent string constants is as string constants. Enums add another layer of indirection which *can* be justified, but it's not clear why you'd need them here.

Comment: I think your on the right way by choosing enums, but enum class can't extend any class as they implicitly extend the Enum class. I would say create seperate enum files for each group and not have them as inner classes as this will make the code very messy

Comment: @nick ah no, I'm not questioning the classes to group them - that's a good idea. I'm asking why you think enums would be better than plain old classes.

Comment: @nickzoum what do you mean by navigating?

Comment: What about giving the enums the "Text" as their constant names?

Comment: @nickzoum do not choose a solution for *efficiency* unless you have a proove. Always prefer readability over *assumed* better performance!

Comment: Using `enum` just for `String` constants is really abusive, your first option is much better IMO, you could use interface instead of class to make then easily accessible from any class by implementing it

Comment: @Nick forget bytecode: is it more efficient to access a static final constant, or to access a static final constant and call a method on it? That's the difference between using a string directly and using an enum to wrap a string.

Comment: @Nick yes. Go for simple. The only thing I would do additionally is to add private constructors to the grouping classes, since it is meaningless to instantiate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As instructed by [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545126/create-group-of-enums-with-common-property-in-java?noredirect=1#comment68329705_40545126), I am still using **`Classes` over `Enums`**.

But I've also made this private constructor:

```
private GroupName(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This class cannot be instantiated.");
}
```

So that this class cannot be instantiated under any circumstances.

Comment: Pls edit, because You suggest some content from Andy, but link is wrong

Comment: "will add 3 extra in each class" 3 extra what? Lines in the source file?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 4: "Enforce noninstantiability with a private constructor", which explains why you shouldn't use `abstract` for this.

Comment: Just a minor comment, but if you want to throw an exception there, maybe `UnsupportedOperationException` is more appropriate than a plain `RuntimeException`.